# Disabled href on datatable script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a table that is fill dynamically, im using codeigniter and jquery and a template.
The template is works with datatable.net v1.9 api
I have created this script - The script disabled the column which contain href field, asociated to a condition.
 The script works, but the problem is:  the return function  not work on columns that are paginated.
The script is like that, to repare the loop closure issue

```js
$(function() {
var indice = <?php echo json_encode($acum);?>;
var table = $('#dt_a').DataTable();
var j=0;
var nodes = new Array();//
for(var i = 0;  i < indice.length; i++)
{   j=i+1;
    nodes.push(table.fnGetData(i )[4]);
      $('#mostrar'+j).click(
        function(num) {
        return function () {
            if(table.fnGetData(num )[4] == 1)
                alert('El usuario seleccionado tiene asociado un Loteo, para primero elimine el Loteo para poder eliminar el usuario');
                return false; }

    }(i)
  )
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable `href` in the callback for raw drawn https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback

```
$('#dt_a').DataTable({
  rowCallback: function ( row, data, index ) {
    // disable `row` content
  }
})
```

`row` will be html-element `tr`

Comment: Thanks , this was the solution

Comment: Can you please update your original question with the solution. Something like **Update** section. This can be useful for other people.